# fields_for text_field doesn't support string data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am examining the complex_form_example project on github. I modified the migration file so that :content changed from t.text to t.string (as shown below): **Please notice that t.string is the only place I changed in the github example project and before the change it all worked.**

```
class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :questions do |t|
      t.integer :survey_id
      t.string :content
##t.text :content
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :questions
  end
end
```

Here is the nested_form_for code:

```
<%= nested_form_for @survey do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <%= f.fields_for :questions, :questions do |g|%>
  <p>
  <%= g.label :content, "Question" %><br />
  <%= g.input :content, :rows => 3 %><br />
  <%= g.link_to_remove "remove" %>
</p>
<%= g.fields_for :answers %>
<p><%= g.link_to_add "Add an answer", :answers %></p>
  <% end %>

  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a question", :questions %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

And now I get the following error message:

```
undefined method `content' for :questions:Symbol

Extracted source (around line #10):

7:   <%= f.fields_for :questions, :questions do |g|%>
8:   <p>
9:   <%= g.label :content, "Question" %><br />
10:   <%= g.text_field :content, :rows => 3 %><br />
11:   <%= g.link_to_remove "remove" %>
12: </p>
13: <%= g.fields_for :answers %>
```

My question is, is there a fields_for field name that supports string type directly?

Answer (score 1):

You have `:questions, :questions`...Do you see that? `:questions` appears two times before `do`

Comment: That's actually necessary for rails 3.1.

Comment: This also doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @JohnJiang Are you talking about `complex-form-examples` of ryanb? This is Rails 3.0.4. And the file [app/views/surveys/_form.html.erb]https://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples/blob/master/app/views/surveys/_form.html.erb has `:questions` used once before `do`. If you are talking about another examples project in github please give link details. Shall I imply also, from your comment, that you are using Rails 3.1? Because it is not clear in your question.

Comment: @Panayotis: Yes you are right I am using rails 3.1. The problem seems to have been resolved. I must have mismatched fields_for with end tag in the view. It seems that as you suggested one :questions tag is enough.

Comment: @JohnJiang Ok. So if you think that my suggestion was helpful, I would appreciate, if not correct answer, a vote up on it. Somebody, put a vote down. I do not know why.

Answer (score 1):

The `fields_for` helper is designed to take an object for which you are building the fields for or, alternatively, the name of the collection of objects which to build fields for.

The first example is something like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :object do |object_fields| %>
  # fields go here
```

In this case, it will build the fields for that object.

The second example is the same, but different:

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |question_fields| 5>
  # fields go here
<% end %>
```

Assuming you have a `questions` method on whatever object `f` is representing, this will iterate through all those objects in that collection and present the same fields for each of the objects.

Please note: *it is not necessary to specify `:questions` a second time*. You only need to tell Rails *once*.

Now, if you're doing this you're probably going to want to have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions` in the parent model (whatever it is that `has_many :questions`) so that the fields are passed through to the controller and into the model's `create` or `update_attributes` calls successfully.

Comment: thank you for your very detailed explanation. Please see my answer below for how I resolved it. I am currently stumped by the fact that I can't save child objects in the nested)form. It works in the complex_form_example project, but in my own project I am not using restful updating of the parent object. So I am not sure how I can force the updating of the parent object to also save the child objects. Your help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have resolved my own issue, by carefully matching fields_for tag with end tag. This works as follows: in view/survey

```
<%= nested_form_for @survey do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |g|%>



  <%= render "question_fields", :f => g %>
  <% end %>



  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a question", :questions %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

In partial _question_fields:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :content, "Question" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :content, :rows => 3 %><br />
  <%= f.link_to_remove "remove" %>
</p>
<%= f.fields_for :answers %>

<p><%= f.link_to_add "Add an answer", :answers %></p>
```

Note that the "f.fields_for :answers" uses the partial _answer_fields by default.